# Cortex-M0 interrupt nesting

Tags: interrupts, cortex-m

Question 1: When one interrupt handler is executed, will it be interrupted if another interrupt with the same priority occurs?

Question 2: When one interrupt handler is executed, will it be interrupted if another interrupt with the lower priority occurs?

I used MSP430. The interrupts are always nested as long as GIE is enabled. The priority is only determine whose interrupt handler is executed first if there are a few interrupts occurred at the same time and pended (before they are responded).
But I don't find any answer for Cortex-M0 in its documents and google search.

Comment: Get DUI0497 *Cortex-M0 Devices Generic User Guide*.

Comment: Thanks, starblue. Just see your comment. You're right. This doc explains to all my questions very clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part that handles these things in a Cortex is the [Nested Vectored Interrupt Controller](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0337e/Cihcbadd.html) (NVIC).

> Question 1: When one interrupt handler is executed, will it be interrupted if another interrupt with the same priority occurs?

No, an interrupt will be acknowledged if it has a *higher* priority

> Question 2: When one interrupt handler is executed, will it be interrupted if another interrupt with the lower priority occurs?

No, not while the interrupt handler is running.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Wouter.

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0337e/Cihcbadd.html

Pre-emption:
**New exception has higher priority than current exception priority or thread and interrupts current flow.**
This is the response to a pended interrupt, causing entry to an ISR if the pended interrupt is higher priority than the active ISR or thread. When one ISR pre-empts another, the interrupts are nested.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Wouter.    

  
In the link below, it is mentioned:  
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0337e/Cihcbadd.html  
  
Pre-emption:  
**New exception has higher priority than current exception priority or thread and interrupts current flow.**  
This is the response to a pended interrupt, causing entry to an ISR if the pended interrupt is higher priority than the active ISR or thread. When one ISR pre-empts another, the interrupts are nested.

Comment: Does this mean that the new exception always has higher prioirty than current one, so the currnt one will be pre-empted no matter theirs designated priorities?

Comment: Supplement: “2.3.5 Exception priorities” in <DUI0497A_cortex_m0_r0p0_generic_ug.pdf> has good information.

Comment: Test results: Same interrupt can’t preempt the running one.